# И еще однокоренные: барыш и барышня

Tags: однокоренные-слова

И еще сразу вопрос: "барыш" и "барышня". Понятно, что "барышня" — производное от "барин". Но имеет ли что-то общее с этими словами слово "барыш"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, не имеет. Барин производное от боярин, болярин, там барышом и не пахнет. 
Барыш же - тюркское, каким бы якобы "туманным" не было его происхождение.